# Join type in ActiveRecord has_one Relationship

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Just getting started with ActiveRecord (in a sinatra app). Trying to port existing queries to AR but getting a little stuck.

if i have a **has_one** relation for users and profiles (using legacy tables unfortunately)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = "systemUsers"
    self.primary_key = "user_id"

    has_one :profile, class_name: 'Profile', foreign_key: 'profile_user_id'
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    self.table_name = "systemUserProfiles"
    self.primary_key = "profile_id"

    belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: 'user_id'
 end
```

if i want to query all users with  profile using an inner join then get the user_age field from the profiles using one query can i do it?

for example 
*(just added .first to reduce code but would be looping through all users with profiles)*

```
user = User.all(:joins => :profile).first
user.profile.user_age
```

gives me the correct data and uses a INNER join for the first query but then issues a **second** query to get the profile data

it also gives a depreciated warning and suggests i use load, which i tried but won't use an inner join.

similar case with

```
user = User.joins(:profile).first
user.profile.user_age
```

i get an INNER join but a query for each user row.

I have tried includes

```
user = User.includes(:profile).first
user.profile.user_age
```

This lazy loads the profile and would reduce the number of queries in the loop, however i think it would pull users without a profile too

I also tried with a reference

```
user = User.includes(:profile).references(:profile).first
user.profile.user_age
```

This gives me the correct data and reduces the queries to 1 but uses a **LEFT JOIN**

I probably have not quite grasped it and am trying to achieve something thats not do-able, i figured i might either need to use includes and check for nil profiles inside the loop or use joins and accept the additional query for each row.

Thought i'd check incase i was missing something obvious.

Cheers

Pat.

Comment: Probably should also mention that i wish to access the whole profile record (Not limited to one field in the examples above)

Answer (score 1):

Profile should always have one user. So, I would do `Profile.first.user_age` for the first user profile. But going by the user approach like you did,

```
User.find { |u| u.profile }.profile.user_age
```

`User.find { |u| u.profile }` returns the first user with `true` value.

To query all the user profiles and get their user_ages. Assuming all profiles has user_id and that should be the case.

```
 Profile.pluck(:user_age)
```

This checks the presence of user_id if you save profiles without user id. This `where.not` is a new feature in Activerecord, check your version.

```
 Profile.where.not(user_id: nil).pluck(:user_age)
```

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately all the users do not necessarily have profiles, which is why there was an inner join in the original first query - they should all have a profile but there is a possibility some do not :(

Comment: Oh! That is why I gave two possible solutions :) So, now, `User.find { |u| u.profile }.profile.user_age` will give the profile of 1st user. `Profile.where.not(user_id: nil).pluck(:user_age)` will give all the user_ages for users who have profile. `Profile.pluck(:user_age)` should also solve the problem.

Comment: Think this way, a user can have or cannot have profile. But a **profile** should always have **user** ? Then all my solution should work :D

Comment: sorry i'm probably still not getting it/or i'm not explaining very well! `Profile.where.not(user_id: nil)` would result in the following query: `SELECT systemUserProfiles.* WHERE (systemUserProfiles.user_id IS NOT NULL)` which would give me all the records in the profile table as everyone would have a corresponding record in systemUsers table as you say, however if want to access the systemUsers.username field i will have to issue another SQL statement to get the corresponding row from systemUsers table.